# Hibernate HQL Query Subselects or Joins

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

In a custom blog platform with User(s), Post(s), and Message(s).
I know how to do an HQL query with distinct Users and their Post count. Also distinct Users and their Message count.

But if I combine the two with "inner join" technique I get the same count for Posts and Messages. I understand why this is happening because of the joins. How could I do sub-selects in the HQL to get the two counts as separately but as one trip to the database?

Here is an example of the last HQL query I tried.

```
   select u.username, count(m), count(p) from User as u 
   inner join u.Messages as m
   inner join u.Posts as p
   group by u.id 
   order by count(m) desc
```

Note: I will be changing the order by based off of an option on a web page.

Comment: take a look at hibernate projections at some point to handle things like this.  Also, i'm not sure if HQL will let you do it but you could do a 'count(distinct m.id)' and 'count(distinct p.id)' like in standard sql.

Comment: Yes, I have to spend some more time looking at Projections. Coming a C# LINQ background I'm still trying to wrap my head around the differences in Projections in LINQ versus Hibernate. +1 for the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select u.username,
       (select count(m.id) from Message m where m.user = u) as messageCount,
       (select count(p.id) from Post p where p.user = u) as postCount
from User u
order by messageCount desc
```

You might have issues with the order by due to the bug http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-892 which is supposed to be fixed, but doesn't seem to be in my version of Hibernate. If it's the case, replace `order by messageCount` by `order by 2`.

But, as Michael J. Lee indicates, you may also use a simple join and distinct count, which should be more efficient :

```
select u.username, count(distinct m.id), count(distinct p.id) from User u 
inner join u.messages m
inner join u.posts p
group by u.username)
order by (count(distinct m.id) desc
```

Using left joins instead of inner joins will also let you get users without any post or without any message.

Comment: Hmmm. Hit by an issue here that no ORDER BY is generated in the SQL no matter what I use messageCount or 2.

Comment: Take that back had a typo. The workaround works. +1 and answer.